# eclipse helios for PHP - code formatter not available

Tags: php, eclipse, helios

I'm looking at my Eclipse helios (3.6) preferences page, and I can see I can set code formatting settings for the Java code, but not for PHP.

How can I set the spacing for function arguments in Eclipse for PHP. It seems the changes I make for Java don't apply to the PHP code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that when I got Eclipse, I downloaded the version that was specifically for PHP: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr1

It's likely that the version you downloaded is the base version and does not have the additional PHP features included.

**EDIT:**
Check out http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/?package_id=8764 for an Eclipse dropin you can use(the site is in Japanese, but I was able to find the download link easily). This may be what you're looking for. To install, just place it in the `dropins` folder of your Eclipse install and restart Eclipse.

Comment: that's the one I've got, if you go in window->preferences->PHP->code style->formatter, there are no deep options like you have for JAVA code

Comment: See my edit for a dropin that is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out that was my problem a couple years ago.

Eclipse maintains a section just for [PHP Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) that includes everything you need for coding PHP in Eclipse.