# How do I use a different PHP formatter in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, formatting, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

This is (I think) related to [eclipse helios for PHP - code formatter not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007525/) but uses a different version and different install instructions -- if it is in fact the same plugin. It seems to be updated and refactored into a plugin rather than a dropin. Anyway

I downloaded a more complete PHP code formatter from here:

http://de.sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/downloads/50253/pdt_tools.formatter_1.0.0.zip/

It comes in .zip form and the instructions say to add it via the usual method:

Help -> Add New Software -> Archive...

This worked, and I see two formatters in Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter, but I can't figure out how to actually *use* the new formatter, or any indication that Eclipse is using the new one. I've looked for a way to remove the old one, or switch something to the new one, or rebind Ctrl+Shift+F to use a specific formatter, but haven't been able to get it... In the project settings it doesn't even show up, only workspace settings. :(

Anyone know how one would do this? Thanks.

Comment: I worked around this by using the "dropin" referenced in the other question. I never found a way to use the newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else is wondering, the newer version (pdt_tools.formatter_1.1.0) works like a charm.

Comment: I'm still wondering; I switched to Zend Studio, which honestly isn't much better. I'll check out 1.1 and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have the old crappy Formatter and Formatter (PDT Tools) options in Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style, and it works. Yay!

Comment: I know, isn't it great?!... still, I'm used to my ol' good netbeans and the way it formats PHP just the way I like.